# Spanish babel and chemformula package

Tags: packages, incompatibility, chemmacros

I need to write a chemical reaction. I use to make this with `mhchem`, but I discover `chemformula`. All it is right but no the arrows when I use the package `babel` in spanish.

There are a problem with spanish babel, because these two codes demonstrate there is a conflict. I need to use spanish `babel` and `chemformula` at the same time.

These are the codes:

The first one:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch {C6H12O6 (s)  +  6 O2 (g) <-> 6 CO2 (g)  +  6 H2O(l)}
\end{document}
```

and the second:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch {C6H12O6 (s)  +  6 O2 (g) <-> 6 CO2 (g)  +  6 H2O(l)}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. And a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234". In your [user profile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/45241) you can also add your settings.

Comment: I'll add something to `chemformula` in order to handle this automatically

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `spanish` module for `babel` changes the behaviour of `<` and `>` to implement some special quotation mechanism.

If you are not using the special quotation mechanism offered by the `spanish` module, add the `es-noquoting` option, so `<` and `>` recover their standard meaning:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch {C6H12O6 (s)  +  6 O2 (g) <-> 6 CO2 (g)  +  6 H2O(l)}
\end{document}
```

Another option, still allowing you to use the quoting features implemented by the `spanish` module would be to deactivate the feature before the formula and then activate it again:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\deactivatequoting
\ch {C6H12O6 (s)  +  6 O2 (g) <-> 6 CO2 (g)  +  6 H2O(l)}
\activatequoting
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in v4.5 (2014/04/08) of `chemmacros`/`chemfomula`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2014/04/08]

\newcommand*\cs[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}

\begin{document}

before: <<foo>>

\ch{C6H12O6\sld{} + 6 O2\gas{} <-> 6 CO2\gas{} + 6 H2O\lqd}

after: <<foo>>

Also inside \cs{ch}'s escaped text:
\ch{"<<foo>>" <<=> "<<bar>>"}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmph. v4.15 broke this again…