# tex4ebook, spanish babel and OpfMetadata configuration

Tags: babel, spanish, tex4ebook

Given a latex file named `tst.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157095/spanish-babel-and-chemformula-package
% \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \usepackage[french]{babel}
% \usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{ttt}

\tableofcontents
\part{ppp}

\end{document}
```

and a configuration file named `tst.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\EndP\HCode{<dc:publisher>puuu</dc:publisher>}}
\EndPreamble
```

and tex4ebook v0.3b with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
returns the error message

```
tex4ebook -c tst.cfg tst.tex
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: tst.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.tex    13       Extra \fi.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.4ct    3        Extra \endcsname.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.tex    13       Extra \fi.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.4ct    3        Extra \endcsname.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.tex    13       Extra \fi.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./tst.4ct    3        Extra \endcsname.
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.4.0
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

How can this error be avoided? Note that the other (commented) babel
languages do not generate such error, only the spanish one does.
Removing the `\tableofcontents` also removes the error.

Comment: This happens even without the `.cfg` file. The issue is that Spanish Babel redefines definition of `\'` accent, which is used in table of contents. I still haven't found a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. The error is caused by the fact that Spanish Babel changes definition of `~` active character. It is used in TOC for `\part` command by TeX4ht. We can fix that by slightly modified version of `\tocpart` macro. This macro is used by TeX4ht to print part entry in the table of contents. Save the following code as `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\tocpart#1#2#3{\par\HCode{<span class="partToc" \a:LRdir>}\if !#1!\else  #1\ \fi #2\HCode{</span>}\par}%
\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\EndP\HCode{<dc:publisher>puuu</dc:publisher>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

There is also other issue, accented characters, such as `í` are printed as `í'I`. This can be fixed using the following version of `spanish.4ht`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% spanish.4ht (2015-02-17-15:57), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright (C) 2000-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2015 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2015-02-17-15:57}

  \expandafter\def\csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname
               #1{\leavevmode \hbox{\csname a:spanish"#1\endcsname}}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space a}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@a@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"a}{1}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space o}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@o@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"o}{1}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space e}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@e@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"e}{1}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space A}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@A@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"A}{1}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space O}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@O@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"O}{1}
\edef\:temp{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:"shorthand\endcsname\space E}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string"@E@\endcsname=\:temp
\NewConfigure{spanish"E}{1}
\edef\:tempc{\expandafter\noexpand
               \csname spanish:'shorthand\endcsname\space i}
\expandafter\HLet\csname spanish@sh@\string'@i@\endcsname=\:tempc
\NewConfigure{spanish'i}{1}
\def\:tempc{\csname a:spanish'i\endcsname}
\expandafter\HLet\csname \string\OT1\string\'-i\endcsname\:tempc
\AtBeginDocument{
   \def\:tempc{\a:guillemotright}
   \HLet\guillemotright\:tempc
   \def\:tempc{\a:guillemotleft}
   \HLet\guillemotleft\:tempc
}
\NewConfigure{guillemotright}{1}
\Configure{guillemotright}{\o:guillemotright:}
\NewConfigure{guillemotleft}{1}
\Configure{guillemotleft}{\o:guillemotright:}
\let\:tempc\es@accent
%\pend:defIII\:tempc{%
\def\:tempc#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\:text@composite@x
    \csname OT1\string#1\endcsname#3\@empty}
\HLet\es@accent\:tempc
\def\:text@composite@x#1#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname \string#1-\string#2\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\ifx \csname \string#1- :\endcsname\relax
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble
      \else
          \expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter
          \csname \string#1- :\endcsname
      \fi
   \else \expandafter\:gobble
   \fi
   {#2}%
   }
\def\chk:acc#1#2#3{%
   \if !#2!\expandafter\:gobbleIII \else
       \if \noexpand#1\noexpand#2%
          \a:es@accents#3\b:es@accents
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gob:accc
       \else
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\chk:acc
       \fi
   \fi
   {#1}%
}
\def\gob:accc#1{\gob:acc}
\def\gob:acc#1#2{\if !#2!\expandafter\gobe:acc
   \else \expandafter\gob:acc\fi
}
\expandafter\ifx\csname documentclass\endcsname\relax\then
   \def\gobe:acc#1\@text@composite#2\@text@composite#3{}
\else
   \let\gobe:acc=\:gobble
\fi
\NewConfigure{es@accent}[2]{\expandafter
   \def\csname #1- :\endcsname##1{\chk:acc{##1}#2{}{}}}
\NewConfigure{es@accents}{2}
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \def\bbl@umlauta{\ifx \EndPicture \:UnDef \expandafter \n:bbl@umlauta:
                    \else \expandafter \o:bbl@umlauta: \fi }%
}

\Hinput{spanish}
\endinput
```

I updated TeX4ht sources, so these fixes should be only temporary, until TeX distributions are updated.

Epub file should be then created correctly:

[image]